# Will closing the MySQL Query Browser kill any running queries it initiated?

Tags: mysql

I could easily determine this myself, however I have a query running (that I initiated in this application) that I cannot terminate.

Comment: FYI I would like to close this application because I am running it in an NX session and I need to bring down ssh for some config changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it does.

You can run `mysqladmin5 processlist` afterwards and check. If it's still there, you'll just have to kill it at the command line, with `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the old GUI tools, so you will probably also have MySQL Administrator on your system. You can login to MySQL administrator -> ServerConnections here you will be able to see the time - state - User and host of all the connections to the MySQL server. You can kill the thread that did not get closed.

BTW : You should try the MySQL Workbench 5.2 - That is the current tool replacing the old MySQL tools.